# Android App - Selecting Image from Phone Gallery and Adding it to a ListView

Tags: android, image, listview, android-imageview

I am using a custom adapter in order to add a selected image to the ListView. I get this error:

```
 04-29 18:15:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(24214): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
04-29 18:15:33.582: E/AndroidRuntime(24214):    at app.photoexpress.ViewAlbumActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(ViewAlbumActivity.java:240)
```

When a photo is added from the gallery, I create a new Photo object and store the given Bitmap in there. And my getBitmap() method calls that but apparently it is null in this case. Not sure what s wrong here

Here is my Code:

```
public class ViewAlbumActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listview;
    ImageAdapter adapter;
    CharSequence[] images;
    int width = 250;
    boolean isSearch = false;
    // ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    TextView title;
    Album album;
    ArrayList<Album> albumList;
    String albumName = "Album";
    Album currentlySelectedAlbum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        // get bundle
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            albumList = (ArrayList<Album>) bundle.getSerializable("albums");
            albumName = bundle.getString("albumName");
            album = Album.findAlbum(albumName, getBaseContext());
            Log.e(".", album.getName());
            setTitle(albumName);
        } else {
            album = new Album("placeholder");
        }

        currentlySelectedAlbum = Album.findAlbum(albumName, getBaseContext());
        ArrayList<Photo> photoList = currentlySelectedAlbum.getPhotos();

        // Displays the icon and album name in the action bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, photoList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // images = readPhotoList();

        // Display display = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        // width = display.getWidth();
        // width=width/2-15;

        /*listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewAlbumActivity.this, ViewPhotoActivity.class);
                // intent.putExtra(name, value)
                intent.putExtra("index", position);
                intent.putExtra("albumname", albumName);
                intent.putExtra("album", album);
                intent.putExtra("isSearch", isSearch);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        if (!isSearch) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.viewalbum, menu);

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        if (!isSearch) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.addPhoto) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                // addPhoto();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            // textTargetUri.setText(targetUri.toString());
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
                //image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Photo photo = new Photo(bitmap);
                currentlySelectedAlbum.addPhoto(photo);
                Album.updateAlbumList(currentlySelectedAlbum, getBaseContext());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * private String[] readPhotoList() { String path =
     * Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/photos/";
     * 
     * File dir = new File(path);
     * 
     * File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
     * 
     * if (filelist == null) { String[] z = new String[1]; z[0] = "no file in "
     * + path; return z; }
     * 
     * if (filelist.length == 0) { String[] s = new String[1]; s[0] =
     * "no image file under " + path; return s; } ArrayList<String> result = new
     * ArrayList<String>(); for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) { if
     * (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + filelist[i].getName()) != null) {
     * result.add(filelist[i].getName()); } } String[] convertList = new
     * String[result.size()]; for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
     * convertList[i] = result.get(i); } return convertList;
     * 
     * }
     */

    /////////////

    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public ArrayList<Photo> photoList2;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Photo> photoList) {
            mContext = c;
            this.photoList2 = photoList;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            int returnInt = 0;
            try {
                returnInt = currentlySelectedAlbum.getPhotos().size();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("NullPointerError", ".");
            }
            return returnInt;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

            View vi = convertView;
            // String fileName="";
            if (convertView == null) {
                /*imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(width, width));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
                LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)ViewAlbumActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                vi  = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customimageview, parent, false);

            } /*else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            // if there is any photo
            if (album.getPhotos().size() != 0) {
                // final String fileName =
                // album.getPhotos().get(position).getName();
                // showImgFromSD("/photos/" + fileName, imageView);
                // showImgFromSD("/photos/002.jpg",imageView);
            }*/

            Bitmap bitmap = photoList2.get(position).getBitmap();
            ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            return imageView;

        }

        /*
         * private void showImgFromSD(String fileName, ImageView iv) { File f =
         * new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
         * FileInputStream input = null;
         * 
         * try { input = new FileInputStream(f); } catch (FileNotFoundException
         * e) { // toastMsg("File: " + fileName + " not found"); return; }
         * Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, null);
         * iv.setImageBitmap(pic);
         * 
         * }
         */
    }

    /*
     * private void addPhoto() { final CharSequence[] options = images;
     * AlertDialog.Builder build = new
     * AlertDialog.Builder(ViewAlbumActivity.this);
     * build.setTitle("../sdcard/photos/"); build.setItems(options, new
     * DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(DialogInterface
     * dialog, int item) { Album tempAlbum = findAlbum(albumName, albumList);
     * Album allPhotos = findAlbum("All Photos", albumList); List<Photo> Photos
     * = tempAlbum.getPhotos();
     * 
     * for (Photo p : Photos) { //if (p.getName().compareToIgnoreCase((String)
     * options[item]) == 0) { toastMsg(options[item] + " already in album");
     * return; } } //Photo tempPhoto = new Photo((String) options[item], "");
     * tempAlbum.addPhoto(tempPhoto); allPhotos.addPhoto(tempPhoto);
     * 
     * // SERIALIZE HERE
     * 
     * // listItems.add((String) options[item]); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     * listview.invalidateViews(); toastMsg(options[item] + " added.");
     * 
     * } }); AlertDialog alert = build.create(); alert.show(); }
     */

    // handles pop up messages
    private void toastMsg(String msg) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = msg;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Album.java:

```
public class Album implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7593044560206879666L;
    String name;
    static ArrayList<Photo> photos;
    boolean previouslySelected = false;

    public Album() {
        photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    }

    public Album(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Album> deleteAlbum(int position, Context context) {

        ArrayList<Album> albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
        albumList = SerializableManager.readSerializable(context, "albumList.ser");

        albumList.remove(albumList.get(position));
        return albumList;

    }

    public static ArrayList<Album> addAlbum(Album a, Context context) {

        ArrayList<Album> albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
        albumList = SerializableManager.readSerializable(context, "albumList.ser");

        for (Album i : albumList) {
            if (i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(a.getName())) {
                Log.e("Not Added", "Album not added because it already exists.");
                CreateNewAlbumActivity.toastMsg("Not added. Album already exists.");
                return albumList;
            }
        }
        albumList.add(a);

        return albumList;

    }

    public static void updateAlbumList(Album a, Context context){

        ArrayList<Album> albumList = SerializableManager.readSerializable(context, "albumList.ser");

        for (int i = 0; i < albumList.size(); i++){
            if (albumList.get(i).getName().equals(a.getName())){
                albumList.remove(i);
                albumList.add(a);
            }
        }

        SerializableManager.saveSerializable(context, albumList, "albumList.ser");

    }

    public static boolean doesAlbumExist(String name, Context context) {

        ArrayList<Album> albumList = SerializableManager.readSerializable(context, "albumList.ser");
        for (Album i : albumList) {
            if (i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    public static Album findAlbum(String name, Context context) {

        ArrayList<Album> albumList = SerializableManager.readSerializable(context, "albumList.ser");
        for (Album i : albumList) {
            if (i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    public static ArrayList<Album> renameAlbum(String oldName, String newName, Context context) {

        ArrayList<Album> albumList = new ArrayList<Album>();
        albumList = SerializableManager.readSerializable(context, "albumList.ser");

        for (Album i : albumList) {
            if (i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(oldName)) {
                Log.e(".", "match found");
                if (!doesAlbumExist(newName, context)) {
                    i.rename(newName);
                }
            }
        }

        return albumList;

    }

    public void rename(String newName) {
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return photos;
    }

    public void addPhoto(Photo p) {
        photos.add(p);
        return;
    }

}
```

Photo.java

```
public class Photo implements Serializable{

    // The Constant storeDir.
    public static final String storeDir = "data\\photo";
    int id;
    String Caption;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    List<Tag> Tags = new ArrayList <Tag>();

    public Photo(Bitmap bitmap) {
    id = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 5000); 
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public  Photo(String caption, Bitmap bitmap) {
        Caption = caption;
        id = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 5000); 

        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }


    public void setCaption(String input)
    {
        Caption = input;
    }

    public boolean hasTag( String type, String value)
    {
        for(Tag s: Tags )
        {
            if(s.Type.compareToIgnoreCase(type) == 0 && s.value.compareToIgnoreCase(value) == 0 )
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean addTag( String type, String value)
    {

        //if tag already there error
        if(!hasTag(type,value))
        {
            Tags.add(new Tag(value,type));
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean deleteTag( String type, String value)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(Tag s: Tags )
        {
            if(s.Type.compareToIgnoreCase(type) == 0 && s.value.compareToIgnoreCase(value) == 0 )
            {
                Tags.remove(count);
                return true;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return false;           
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "no";
    }

    public List<Tag> getTags()
    {
        return Tags;
    }


    public String getCaption()
    {
        return Caption;
    }


    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
        return bitmap;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o==null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!(o instanceof Photo)) {return false;}
        Photo other = (Photo)o;
        return (true);

        //FIX THIS
    }
}
```

customimageview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your stacktrace you start with it looks like the error happens on this line (A bit hard without knowing that this is actually line 240):

thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

As your error is a NullPointer it means that thumbnail is null and that tells us that:

ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

Fails to find an ImageView. So to get to the root we would need to see the xml of:

R.layout.customimageview

But it seems likely that there is no imageView with the ID of imageView1 in there. If there is none adding one should solve the nullpointer.
If this is not the case and there is an ImageView in there we will keep on investigating. :) (but post your xml then as well and please confirm exactly which line 240 is.)

Edit:

Also looking on your code your adapter is not fully implemented and you will probably get other errors later if this is not fixed. For example the methods getItem and getItemId.

getItem should probably look something like this:

```
  public Object getItem(int position) {
      return photolist2.get(position);
  }
```

and getItemId:

```
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Edit2:

Also, while Serializable is handy and easy it does come with some negative aspects, for example speed on Android and it could be good to look up Parceble and to help you with the boilderplate code: https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler. But that's for a later time ;)

Edit 3:

Looking more on the Adapter code it contained a few errors, this should be closer to what you want:

class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

```
    public ArrayList<Photo> photoList2;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Photo> photoList) {
        mContext = c;
        this.photoList2 = photoList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        int returnInt = 0;
        try {
            returnInt = currentlySelectedAlbum.getPhotos().size();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e("NullPointerError", ".");
        }
        return returnInt;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return photoList2.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi;

        // String fileName="";
        if (convertView == null) {
            /*imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(width, width));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);*/
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)ViewAlbumActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi  = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customimageview, parent, false);

        } else {
           vi = convertView;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = photoList2.get(position).getBitmap();
        ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return vi;
    }
```

So what's the difference? In your adaptor you create and ImageView at the top and return that view at the end. So when Android calls getView again with the convertView, the convertView now holds that ImageView object and not a view of customimageview that you created. So when vi.findViewByid was called it was trying to find an ImageView inside an ImageView, and therefore failed.

Comment: I have added the xml. I do have that image view :/

Comment: Okay, can you post the xml and confirm which line 240 is? :)

Comment: I have added it and I can confirm that line 240 is that line

Comment: Hmm it seems that if (convertView == null) does not run because if I inflate the display outside of that the error disappears. Why is that happening? @nerevar

Comment: Yeah I was a bit quick and missed a thing. I made an edit to the answer with an updated adapter for you.

Comment: In short what Android tries to do with the converter view is to reuse the objects already created. 

So if the converterView is null, Android has not yet created a view and thus you inflate the view you want to display in there.
When Android comes back and the convertView isn't null it means android wants to try and reuse the code. So we put the created view in vi and update the photo in the already created view. Does that make a bit of sense? :)